# Oracle apex changing pages of interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex

it is possible to use page item (text field) to change pagination of interactive grid?

e.q Interactive grid is divided into 10 pages and i can input number from 1 - 10 to change pagination.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Don't think you can because adding an order by clause in the query is not allowed. Do you need an interactive grid ? I think this can be done in a classic report.

Comment: I also can use classic report. Is there any easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on the EMP table. I'm showing 4 rows at a time with a select list to change pages:

- Create page item P106_PAGE_NO, type select list with 5 rows, return values 0 to 4.
- Create Classic report with source:

```
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO
  from EMP
ORDER BY ename ASC
OFFSET NVL(:P106_PAGE_NO,1) * 4 ROWS FETCH FIRST 4 ROWS ONLY
```

Page items to submit: P106_PAGE_NO

- Create a dynamic action on change of P106_PAGE_NO with a true action of refresh the classic report region.

That should be it - change the 4 to whatever nr of rows you need. Make sure that the "Number of rows" attribute of the classic report is set to higher than the nr of rows per page you have in the query.